# How to create a facebook logout button in UITableViewCell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, uitableview, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook API to login and logout.

In my initial view controller I put a facebook button for Login and it worked.

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class SignInViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let facebookLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        view.addSubview(facebookLoginButton)

        facebookLoginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 50, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 50)
        facebookLoginButton.delegate = self
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("Log out!")
    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }

        print("Success!")

        let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let desController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
        self.present(desController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

After this I created a `UITableViewController` for the app menu
and in this menu I created a `UITableViewCell` and put a button.

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class LogOutTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnLogOut: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func btnLogOutAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("clicked!")
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("LogOut!")
    }

}
```

I would like to facebook logout when click in this button.

I'm have an error in `LogOutTableViewCell` : `Type LogOutTableViewCell does not conform to protocol FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate`

Does anyone know how I fix this problem? Or does anyone know another solution to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The error says that your LogOutTableViewCell does not conform the Protocol FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate

**Solution**

Just add the methods `loginButton(_:didCompleteWith:error:)` and `loginButtonDidLogOut(_:)` to your LogOutTableViewCell, to conform the protocol. In your case, you can leave it empty, because you do your login in your SignInViewController.

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
  // just leave it empty
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
  print("did logout of facebook")
}
```

**Update:**

Because you use your own `@IBAction`, you probably don't need the `FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate`. It's probably enough just to call `FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()` in your `@IBAction` like this:

```
@IBAction func btnLogOutAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
  print("clicked!")
  FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
}
```

Comment: Where I add it? I tryed and receive another error : `Use of unresolved identifier loginButton(_:didCompleteWith:error:)`

Comment: Yeah, great that I could help you!